# Tkinter Messagebox causing Entry to disable

Tags: python, tkinter, messagebox, tkinter-entry

So I was creating a simple input window with Tkinter but whenever i have a showinfo displaying i can't type in the entry box

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.messagebox import *


root = tk.Tk()
root.title("hello world")
root.minsize(700,600)

abc = StringVar()
abc.set("abc")
Entry(root, bd = 1, width = 50, textvariable=abc).pack(side = TOP)
showinfo('info', 'hello')
root.mainloop()
```

I'm not sure if there is something wrong with my Python (3.4) or tkinter but whenever i take out the showinfo line I can type into the Entry box but when its there i can't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

tkinter messagebox default dialog boxes are [modal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modal_window). What this means is that you need
to close the child window(the tkinter messagebox) before you can return to the parent application.

So, there is nothing wrong with your python or tkinter; This behavior is intended.

Don't show the tkinter messagebox before the event loop is started. Try this:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.messagebox import *


 def callback():
     showinfo("info", "hello")

 root = tk.Tk()
 root.title("hello world")
 root.minsize(700,600)

 abc = StringVar()
 abc.set("abc")
 Entry(root, bd=1, width=50, textvariable=abc).pack(side=TOP)
 Button(root, text="OK", command=callback).pack()
 root.mainloop()
```

Comment: I close the infobox every time but the Entry is frozen, I added a button with some functionality and it works perfectly after i close the infobox. I have tried hitting 'x' and ok but nothing makes the entry box functional.

Comment: This maybe because you are showing the tkMessageBox before you start the event loop. Try using a callback like I have edited the answer to include.

Comment: so i added that and it works but I trigger the showinfo box to pop up on an if statement in my actual code, i can't trigger it on a button press. Am i using infobox wrong, is it not supposed to be called like a normal "function", like do I need to call it from a button for it to work properly?

Comment: could you edit your question to include your code with the if statement?

Comment: you can definitely use it within an if statement

Comment: thanks man, i understood what you meant, I didn't let the code run to the mainloop, my actual code was initializing some variable after the GUI was setup and a infobox would pop as a prompt. I added the variable initialing in as a variable

Comment: @deborah-digges Please, change this code to Python 3. The question is related to Python 3 not Python 2, and you should give an answer in that direction.

Answer (score 1):

The solution i made for this is overriding the messagebox.showerror so for example i made

```py
import logging
from tkinter import messagebox

                                                           
logging.basicConfig(                                            
    level=logging.DEBUG,                                        
    format='%(asctime)s [%(levelname)s] %(name)s "%(message)s"',
)                                                               
LOGGER = logging.getLogger(__name__)                            

def test_showerror(title, message):              
    LOGGER.debug(f'{title} Message -> {message}')

messagebox.showerror = test_showerror
```

actually that's how i deal with many problems that face me during writing tests.. i override utility functions to add logging or avoid a case.